# question got closed a little too bluntly

Tags: discussion

My [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37099/l-function-returning-a-link-with-unwanted-string-of-title-attributes-of-an-img) got closed for something that I can't really change. I posted a screenshot of a site that has dutch text in it so it got closed for being too 'localized' by [googletorp](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/190/googletorp)

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too localized, isn't related to your site being dutch:

> This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question more broadly applicable, see the FAQ.

It's fine to ask help with code, but asking question about why a specific piece of code with some specific content doesn't do as expected it a but too much. It's not really possible to answer the question without being able to debug your site, which was why I felt the question is too localized.

Comment: I got it from the wrong angle to begin with indeed. Thanks for the feedback I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The question has not been closed as too localized because the Dutch text, but because it thought not to help any future reader.
A question is also closed as too localized when it is not possible to reproduce what reported in the question, such as in the case the configuration of the web site is too specific to be able to reproduce the issue, for example because the site is using a custom module for which the OP doesn't shown the code.

What you should add to the question is:

- The content of `$samples[$i]`, and `$originals[$i]` for the row shown in the screenshot
- The HTML returned from `l()`

It would have helped if you didn't add details that are not necessary to answer the question. I also thought the question was too localized when I first read it; at the third time I read it, I understood exactly what you were asking, but I still don't have the necessary information to answer it, which is what I reported in the previous points here.

Keep in mind that a question can always be re-opened, if the question is edited to require the necessary information, or if the question is made not too localized.

Comment: Thank you for your great effort. I added the return values of those variables and the l() function. Hope that that makes the question better to work with for anyone.